# S/MIME signed email loses attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook, digital-signature, smime

We have a small number of users who digitally sign (but don't encrypt) their email. When they send attachments, it usually works fine. However, when the recipient is using Outlook Mobile, all attachments disappear for them leaving behind only the S/MIME p7m file. Is this a known problem, and is there a solution besides not signing the message?

What we suspect so far is that the sending client is bundling the other attachments inside the p7m, ignoring the facts that 1) the message is signed but not encrypted, and 2) some clients might not be able to extract them again.

Comment: This is not a known problem.  Sounds like a configuration issue with the client and/or server.  What that configuration error, I could not determine, based on only the information provided.  I assume the certificates were installed on the device?

Comment: You state "when using Outlook Mobile" - do you mean on the sending or the receiving end, or both?

Comment: On the receiving end.

Comment: Not sure, if this could be connected, but there is an older known issue with encrypted emails sent _from_ Outlook, but there is also a fix available: [Some email clients unable to decrypt email sent from Outlook 2010](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2142236/some-email-clients-unable-to-decrypt-email-sent-from-outlook-2010)

Answer (score 1):

*Updated answer now includes opaque signatures*

The **p7m** usually is an **encrypted email message** (including all attachments), but it is required to know the `Content-type` to definitely know it. If you can see only a p7m attachment in the receiving mail client, this *may* mean that the mail has been encrypted in whole and the receiving client hasn’t been able to decrypt the S/MIME message.

The reasons can vary, and it‘s hard to say without further details. The most obvious cause would be that the recipient‘s private key ist not available or not associated with the email address configured in the receiving client.

To verify if the message is signed or encrypted, take a look at the raw email message.

#### Encrypted contents

In an encrypted email, you will find headers like:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime; name="smime.p7m"; smime-type=enveloped-data
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="smime.p7m"
```

Followed by the encoded encrypted email.

**Signed emails**, however, can come in two different flavors. Quoted from [RFC 8551](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8551#page-31):

> There are two formats for signed messages defined for S/MIME:
>
> - application/pkcs7-mime with SignedData.
> - multipart/signed.
>
> In general, the multipart/signed form is preferred for sending, and
> receiving agents MUST be able to handle both.

#### Detached signatures

So-called detached signatures are the most common signatures. The mail contents is kept in clear-text, and the signatures is attached to the email. For such a signed email, you should find a Content-type headers like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed;
    boundary="BC5E686BA36";
    protocol="application/pkcs7-signature";
    micalg=sha1
```

And probably near the end of the same message:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename=smime.p7s
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-signature;
    name=smime.p7s
```

Followed by the encoded signature. If it‘s *only* signed, you should be able to see the message text.

#### Opaque signatures

However, there are also so-called opaque signatures, which encode the full contents in the signature, so the email does not contain clear-text any more. In this case, you should find these headers:

```
Content-Type: application/pkcs7-mime;
    smime-type=signed-data;
    name="smime.p7m"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
    filename="smime.p7m"
```

Note that the filename looks like in an encrypted email, but the MIME type is different.

#### Conclusion

Again quoted from [RFC 8551](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8551#page-31):

> Messages signed using the multipart/signed format can always be
> viewed by the receiver whether or not they have S/MIME software.
> They can also be viewed whether they are using a MIME-native user
> agent or they have messages translated by a gateway.  In this
> context, "be viewed" means the ability to process the message
> essentially as if it were not a signed message, including any other
> MIME structure the message might have.
>
> Messages signed using the SignedData format cannot be viewed by a
> recipient unless they have S/MIME facilities.  However, the
> SignedData format protects the message content from being changed by
> benign intermediate agents.  Such agents might do line wrapping or
> content-transfer encoding changes that would break the signature.

So if you see only p7m-Attachments in the email client, possible causes are

- the email is encrypted, but the email client does not have the corresponding private key available to decrypt the message
- the email is opaque-signed, but the email client does not support opaque signatures

The latter was the case with Outlook Web App (OWA), but I don't know if it still is.

Comment: The thing is, none of the recipients _have_ a private key. The message is signed only, and its body appears intact at the other end.

Answer (score -1):

I believe Outlook mobile doesn't support S/MIME. That is why you will not be able to read digitally signed emails nor send them from it.